# Parse human readable dates with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, human-readable

I'm working on a web project that uses Django, jQuery and Google App Engine.
I need an option to parse raw, human readable date texts into JavaScript Date objects.
I found this library - http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/ which will allow me to parse strings such as "tomorrow at noon" or "in 5 minuts" to epoch time. The drawback is that its a python library, thus requiring me to use AJAX to send a request to convert the string for me to the server. 
Is there a JavaScript library that will allow for a similar functionality that I can use to parse the string on the client-side?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this: http://www.datejs.com/

Comment: Hey, yea i've seen this one. Its okay, but not perfect and doesn't really have all I need. are there any more libraries such as this one?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout moment.js: http://momentjs.com/docs/